# Bringing an electric gun in the streets (Belgium)

Tags: self-defense

Is it permissible to bring an electric gun in a hoster just in case of self-defense? Is there a need of a special written permission by a police department or a weapon center or by a court? What are the bureaucratic steps to entertain for this? 
Even if it is GENERALLY illegal, can I ask for a specific permission and get it through a hard bureaucratic process?

Jurisdiction: Belgium

Comment: Do you mean a [taser](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser)?

Comment: At least in the U.S. Taser is a registered trademark. The generic name here seems to be stun gun.

Comment: If you claim you want to bring a gun with you "just in case for self defense" then you have just admitted that you intend to use the gun. I don't know how Belgium handles this. In the UK, a whole bunch of _armed_ police officers would come down on you like a brick wall. They have the theory that the safest way for everyone to handle armed criminals is to come down on them with overwhelming force.

Comment: You didn't read "Electric gun" I guess. I don't intend bullet gun

Comment: It seems fantastic to me that a squad of armed UK officers would come down on someone asking if they are allowed to carry a particular weapon for the purpose of self-defense, even if the answer is no, if they have no reason to believe the person actually intends to break the law.  I mean, I have a low opinion of the prioritization of UK police resources, but even mine isn't that low.

Comment: @abdu then you should have included a link to the term to avoid confusion.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Why? Considering that the weapon is forbidden, why should you **not** expect the police to proctect citizens from other citizens who disobey the law? That is,  after all, their job. Their job is **not** to proctect criminals, but citizens.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The OP asks whether or not carrying a particular weapon is permissible - the question doesn't mention owning one, intention to buy or carry one regardless of legality, or any language that would lead a person to believe the OP intends to break the law.  The answer seems to imply that a person can't even safely ask whether a particular act is legal without the authorities breaking down their front door.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian No, it doesn't. You may **apply** for a permit.   The answer implies that it will not be granted. A ratical difference, since the one is only a stamp and the other (your interpretation) a costly affair that **responsible, realistic** peaple will avoid.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Based on your answer, there is no permit application process in the UK, so I'm not sure what permit the OP has applied for in that hypothetical.  If they are in Belgium, our poorly defined hypothetical seems to imply that the OP has applied for a permit pursuant to the Weapons Act, with the justification of self-defense, and the authorities for some reason take the OP's earnest attempt to follow the legal process with insufficient justification to be issued the permit as evidence that they currently own a weapon illegally and intend to carry it illegally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100649/discussion-between-illusivebrian-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes that with the term **electric gun** that you mean a [electric gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#United_Kingdom), which is also called a **Taser**.

> > Is it permissible to bring an electric gun in a hoster just in case of self-defense?

With the exception of **Austria**, such devices are generally forbidden.

In many, the police were allowed to use them, but that is now often restricted.

Therefore for Belgium, you would need a permit issued against the **Weapons Act 2006**.

The chances for such a permit, to also be carried openly in a holster, for the general purpose of self defense is **very unlikely**

- such permits are mostly only granted when the applicant is deemed by the authorities to be in great danger

---

**Sources**:

- [electric gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#United_Kingdom) (English)

> **United Kingdom**
>   Tasers are considered "**prohibited weapons**" under the Firearms Act 1968 and possession is an offence.

- [Pistolet à impulsion électrique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistolet_%C3%A0_impulsion_%C3%A9lectrique#Belgium) (French)

> **France**
>   The Taser is classified as a Category B weapon (as is, for example, a 357 Magnum with a barrel: **a weapon subject to authorization**).
>
> **Belgium**
>   The **possession and carrying a taser by an individual is banned**, as defined in the Weapons Act 2006

- [Elektroimpulswaffe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektroimpulswaffe) (German)

> **Germany**
>   Distance electro-pulse devices (such as Airtaser) **are generally prohibited** in Germany since April 1, 2008 and are not eligible.
>
> **Switzerland**
>   In Switzerland, the transfer, acquisition, transfer and transfer of electroshock devices "that can impair people's resilience or permanently damage their health" **is prohibited**.
>
> **Austria**
>   Under § 1 Z 1 WaffG 1996 is thus confirmed that z.  B. o. A.  Stun gun "[...] **is essentially designed to eliminate or reduce the ability to attack or defend people by direct action [...]" and that it is *not a prohibited weapon*** gem.  Paragraph 17 (1) is worded as follows: 'Forbidden is the acquisition, importation, possession, and keeping of arms, the form of which is capable of simulating another object, or which are disguised with objects of daily use;'

- [Spanish weapons law](http://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Admin/rd137-1993.html#a5) limits electric guns for the use of state security/military forces:

> Article 5
>   It is forbidden the marketing, trade, ownership and use, except by state agents specially allowed, and in line with the dispositions of the several regulations of:
>   [..]
>   c) electric defenses<sup>1</sup>, rubber defenses, tonfas or similar

<sup>1</sup> And yes, electric defenses include electric guns.

Comment: They are legal to carry in most of the states in the U.S. I believe the consumer versions are not as powerful as those sold to law enforcement.